# How can I convert 2-dimensional float array to float buffer?

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, kotlin

I am trying to feed input data to a tflite model in Kotlin, however, I have no idea for this input form. My point is how I can convert 2-dimensional float array float buffer as input shape.

```
val inputArray: Array<FloatArray> = ...
var byteBuffer: ByteBuffer = allocateDirect(10 * 100 * 4)
var inputBuffer: FloatBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
inputBuffer.put(inputArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
val row = inputArray.size
val col = inputArray[0].size
val byteBuffer: ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*col*row)
byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
for (i in 0 until row){
  for (j in inputArray[i].indices){
     byteBuffer.putFloat(inputArray[i][j])
  }
}
```